# Comparing two TCHAR's with same value results false

Tags: c++, compare, tchar, getmodulefilename

I am trying to check my applications path, and if it is not a specified path, then move it. I feel like my code is solid, yet it does not work properly.

```
TCHAR pCheck[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR xPath[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileName(NULL,xPath,MAX_PATH);

if(SHGetSpecialFolderPath(HWND_DESKTOP, pCheck, CSIDL_DESKTOP, FALSE)){
    wcscat(pCheck,L"\\NewFile.exe");
    MessageBox(NULL,pCheck,NULL,NULL);
    MessageBox(NULL,xPath,NULL,NULL);
    if(pCheck!=xPath){  
        CopyFile(xPath,pCheck,0);
        ShellExecute(0,L"open",pCheck,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
        return 0;
    }else{
        MessageBox(NULL,L"New Location",NULL,NULL); 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Even when the file is in the new path it will still result pCheck != xPath

I never get the "New Location" messagebox. When first two messageboxs are displayed, the path's are equal...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are just comparing  the addresses of the arrays (which obviously are never the same). If you want to compare the two strings held in the arrays you should use `_tcscmp();`

```
if(_tcscmp(pCheck, xPath) != 0){
```

Comment: Thank you. I will select as answer in 10 mins when it lets me.

Comment: Note: `_tcsicmp` for case-insensitive comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

Your TChar array decays into a **pointer to the first character.** You are currently checking for pointer equality, which is why you never get **TRUE**.

Use `strcmp` equivalents, for TChar, like **[`_tcscmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.

_tcscmp is a **macro**, which either invokes `wcscmp` or `strcmp` depending on the type of characters.